# Link to download image instead of view image

Tags: html, image, amazon-s3, download, href

I need to provide website visitors a link to download an original high resolution image.  If I simply link to the image with a href="image.jpg", the browser displays the image.  How do I make the browser download it?

I'm using amazon S3 to server these images... If this requires having a special header set on the image, I'm sure it's possible.. but I also want to display these images sometimes.  Any tips on making this work with S3 would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. There are some headers needed to do this. These would be:

```
Content-type: image/png
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some_image.png"
```

I am not sure how S3 handles this but if you want do display these images, the `Content-Disposition` header should be left out.

**EDIT:** Displaying the image via `<img src="some_image.png" alt="" />` continues to work even with both headers being sent. The image displays nicely in my tests.

Comment: Unfortunately S3 doesn't allow you to serve the same file with different headers, so I'd need to duplicate all files..  Would I still be able to let users view a downloadable file using img src="image.jpg"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the content-disposition header to let the client download the image:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>
```

Comment: ok, so I can add this with S3 and have it exposed through CloudFront too.  I guess the problem is users will no longer be able to view the full image without me duplicating it without that header.  Can I still inline the image in html if it has that header?