# download tag on HTML for Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I cannot use download tag like `<a href="download.jpg" download>` in Internet Explorer 8. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: No. You would have to just ask people to right click and choose download.

Comment: Dr.Avalanche, you linked to the 1999 spec (15 years ago), rather than the current one: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#downloading-resources . This attribute has it's own section in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link to download image instead of view image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651093/link-to-download-image-instead-of-view-image)